# How do I make my winforms UI update quicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I have two Intel RealSense Cameras capturing and recording data. I am capturing frames for awhile and then taking the data and updating the UI with it, but it comes in spurts. I want to have a seemingly continuous flow of data coming in.

I've tried by making an asynchronous event that goes through the frames and updates as seen below:

```
private async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            ButtonStart.Enabled = false;
            try
            {
                Context context = new Context();
                // var dev = context.QueryDevices();
                //Declare RealSense pipeline, encapsulating the actual device and sensors
                /*
                Pipeline pipe = new Pipeline();
                //create a config for the pipeline
                var cfg = new Config();
                //add the T265 Pose stream
                cfg.EnableStream(Stream.Pose);
                //start the stream
                var pp = pipe.Start(cfg);
                */
                Config config = new Config();
                var dev = ctx.QueryDevices();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var device in dev)
                {
                    config.EnableDevice(dev[i].Info[CameraInfo.SerialNumber]);
                    config.EnableAllStreams();
                    Pipeline p = new Pipeline(ctx);
                    p.Start(config);
                    pipelines[i] = p;
                    i++;
                }
                //Pipeline pipe2 = new Pipeline();
                //var cfg2 = new Config();
                //cfg2.EnableStream(Stream.Color);
                //cfg2.EnableStream(Stream.Depth);
                // var pp2 = pipe2.Start(cfg2);
                //variables for direction change
                float lastX = -300;
                float lastY = -300;
                float lastZ = -300;
                string dx = "";
                string dy = "";
                string dz = "";
                //main loop for frames
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        using (var frames = pipelines[1].WaitForFrames())
                        {
                            var f = frames.FirstOrDefault(Stream.Pose);
                            var pose_data = f.As<PoseFrame>().PoseData;

                            if (lastX != -300)
                            {
                                //x
                                if (lastX > pose_data.translation.x)
                                {
                                    dx = "LEFT";
                                }
                                else if (lastX < pose_data.translation.x)
                                {
                                    dx = "RIGHT";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dx = "";
                                }

                                //y
                                if (lastY > pose_data.translation.y)
                                {
                                    dy = "DOWN";
                                }
                                else if (lastY < pose_data.translation.y)
                                {
                                    dy = "UP";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dy = "";
                                }
                                //z
                                if (lastZ > pose_data.translation.z)
                                {
                                    dz = "FORWARD";
                                }
                                else if (lastZ < pose_data.translation.z)
                                {
                                    dz = "BACKWARD";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    dz = "";
                                }
                            }
                            //update the UI
                            UpdateUI(pose_data.translation.x.ToString(), pose_data.translation.y.ToString(), pose_data.translation.z.ToString(), dx, dy, dz);                         
                            //Set last x,y,z to see what change occurred
                            lastX = pose_data.translation.x;
                            lastY = pose_data.translation.y;
                            lastZ = pose_data.translation.z;
                            dx = "";
                            dy = "";
                            dz = "";
                        }
                    }
                });                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            } //end catch
            ButtonStart.Enabled = true;
}


public void UpdateUI(string x, string y, string z, string dx, string dy, string dz)
{
            var timeNow = DateTime.Now;

            if ((DateTime.Now - previousTime).Milliseconds <= 15) return;
            //object o = new object();
            //label for x
            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {

                LabelXPosition.Text = o.ToString();

            }), x);
            //label for y
            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                //Set the labels for x,y,z 
                LabelYPosition.Text = o.ToString();

            }), y);
            //label for z
            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                //Set the labels for x,y,z 
                LabelZPosition.Text = o.ToString();

            }), z);
            //label for dx
            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                //Set the labels for x,y,z 
                LabelLR.Text = o.ToString();

            }), dx);
            //label for dy
            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                //Set the labels for x,y,z 
                LabelUD.Text = o.ToString();

            }), dy);
            //label for dz
            synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o =>
            {
                //Set the labels for x,y,z 
                LabelFB.Text = o.ToString();

            }), dz);

            previousTime = timeNow;
}
```

Is there any way I can stop it from "freezing" up while reporting the data?

Comment: I see an UpdateUI that looks like it's in a `while (true)` loop.  Guessing you are updating the gui too often.

Comment: @LarsTech Do you have any suggestions on a better approach to constantly trying to poll the camera for data without the while loop? Perhaps running it in the background on a separate thread would be a better solution?

Comment: You can't update the gui on a separate thread.  Aren't you already in a separate thread with the Task.Run?  Try adding a counting variable so you can control how often you update the gui.  `if (counter >= 500) { counter = 0; blah-blah-blah}`  experiment with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Device initialization

If device initialization does not need synchronization context then just include entire try body into a task:

```
private async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ButtonStart.Enabled = false;
  try 
  {
    await Task.Run(() => {
      Context context = new Context();
      Config config = new Config();
    ...
    }
  } catch {
  ...
  }
}
```

Initialization will be dispatched in the thread pool thread and UI won't freeze.
Please note that creating methods that are `async` and return `void` is a [bad practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), event handler is [an exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) though.

#### UI dispatch

Inside of `UpdateUI` you dispatch 6 messages to synchronization context to update 6 labels. You can group everything to a single update:

```
synchronizationContext.Post(_ => { 
  LabelXPosition.Text = x.ToString();
  LabelYPosition.Text = y.ToString()
  ...
}, null));
```

There is a small overhead on capturing your variable to closure, however, you have less events dispatched in the UI thread and also you don't box all of them by casting to an `object` in `Post` method (second argument).

#### DateTime.Now

`DateTime.Now` is rather expensive operation as it converts time to current timezone. `DateTime.UtcNow` is more lightweight. However, for your purposes I think [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) will be much more suitable.

#### Throttling inside UpdateUI

There are 2 concerns here: too small time and functional issue in the algorithm.

You don't update UI if time between frames is less than 15ms:

```
if ((DateTime.Now - previousTime).Milliseconds <= 15) return;
```

Please note, that 15ms is a rather small value and I bet none user will be able to handle such refresh rate in your labels :). I think even 150ms will be too fast, so please consider a bigger value.

Also your implementation has functional issue because you drop UI dispatch inside `UpdateUI`, so you may report incorrect data to user, for example:

```
 1. t=0;  x=0;                   lastX=0 
 2. t=15; x=100; label=Right;    lastX=100
 3. t=20; x=300; <don't update>; lastX=300
 4. t=30; x=250; label=Left;     lastX=250
```

You reported to user that Pose moved to the `Right` when `x=100` and then reported that it moved `Left` when `x=250` what is not correct.

I'd recommend to move throttling logic to the loop so that you don't have this issue:

```
val sw = StopWatch.StartNew()
using (var frames = pipelines[1].WaitForFrames())
{
  if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 150) continue;
  ...
  sw.Restart()
}
```

### Other considerations

#### Pull vs Push

You are using push model by dispatching messages in your synchronization context. Instead you can pass these details through the state and update UI using `Timer`:

```
// Form fields:
Vector3 _currentLocation;
Vector3 _dispatchedLocation;
System.Windows.Forms.Timer _poseTimer;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 _poseTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.Container){Interval=150};
 _poseTimer.Tick += displayPoseChange;
}

private void displayPoseChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // compare _currentLocation to _dispatchedLocation
 // update labels
 // replace _dispatchedLocation with _currentLocation 
}

// ButtonClick method
poseTimer.Start()
...
using (var frames = pipelines[1].WaitForFrames()) {
  _currentLocation =  pose_data.translation // just update the field
  ...
}
...
poseTimer.Stop()
...
```

#### Rx.NET

You are processing frames from the pipeline and there is a great framework that could be very handy for that: [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive)

```
var pipeline = await initializePipeline();
var obs = Observable.FromEvent(
            callback => pipeline.Start(callback), 
            _ => pipeline.Stop());
obs.Where(Stream.Pose) // get only Poses
   .Select(f => f.As<PoseFrame>().PoseData) // select only what we need
   .Where(pose_data => pose_data.translation.x != -300) // filter out?
   .Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)) // throttle the UI
   .Buffer(2, 1) // gives you last and current items
   .ObserveOn(this) // dispatch on the UI
   .Subscribe(data => {var last=data[0]; var current=data[1]; /* update labels*/});
await obs.GetAwaiter();
```

Code above shows you the idea but I didn't try to compile it, so you might need to alight types.

More [documentation](http://reactivex.io/intro.html) and [examples](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc38).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Background Worker](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/backgroundworker-in-C-Sharp/) in order to do the process without freezing the form. If the concern is on the speed of the process execution and it involves a loop, you can use [Task-Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

Example is Parallel.Foreach

```
Parallel.ForEach(dev, device=>  {  
    config.EnableDevice(dev[i].Info[CameraInfo.SerialNumber]);
    config.EnableAllStreams();
    Pipeline p = new Pipeline(ctx);
    p.Start(config);
    pipelines[i] = p;
    i++;;  
});
```